# What does a rich man put in his pocket, that a poor man does not?

Tags: riddle

What is it that if a rich man had it he would usually put in his pocket, but if a poor man had it he would usually discard.

It is not something that only a rich man may have; a poor man may have it too.

There is no legal issue that would influence the behaviour of either man.

You may assume that poor men have pockets.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, I find this a very poor, low quality riddle.  I don't even agree with the answer.  This was (eventually) sandboxed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And since I am experiencing this bad cold, the answer is:

> Nasal mucus!

Why?

> If rich man had it he would usually put in his pocket **using a handkerchief.**
>  But if a poor man had it he would usually discard it, **picking up the nose and let it go!**
>  Both have nasal mucus, and the world doesn't care about what these polar opposites of society do with it unless they're spreading a contagious disease.

Comment: I was looking for "snot", but I got pwned. WD

Comment: It's just "pick", not "pick up"

Answer (score 4):

I bet this isn't the answer the questioner has in mind, but it seems to me to work tolerably well.

> Anything that provides a substantial benefit to the holder but is only any use if you have money. For instance: a half-price voucher for some fantastically expensive musical production; a ticket entitling the bearer to attend the opening of a new shop selling (only) very fancy jewelry.

Now, arguably

> if a poor person came into possession of one of these things they could sell it to a rich person. But if I imagine (say) that I am desperately poor, I pull a newspaper out of a roadside litter bin to stuff inside my clothes to keep me warm at night, and out falls a voucher offering 20% off a new Ferrari, I'm probably not going to go out in search of a rich gearhead to sell it to.

A possibly more cogent objection is that

> most things in this category will be of interest to *some* rich men but not all. (I don't think there is any level of wealth at which I would be very interested in a 20%-off voucher for Ferraris. Though I might try to sell one if I had it.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> A receipt. Only the "rich man" with a more complex tax situation might *usually* keep a receipt.

I feel it's not a great answer, but the only one I can come up with that fits.  The word "usually" in the question helps my answer a lot.

Comment: I think the exact opposite: A rich man may not bother returning a defective item because he could just buy a replacement, so he may not keep receipts especially for low cost items. A poor man could not afford to do be so frivolous - each purchased item would be precious, so he would be *more* likely to keep his receipts in case of problems. It could be argued that a found receipt has intrinsic value too: if a poor man found a receipt, he may be able to sell it to a person who bought the same item and wants to return it but lost their receipt. A rich man wouldn't bother keeping a found receipt.

Comment: Counter-examples are easy.  I could say that your kleenex/handerchief answer does not correlate with wealth.  I provided what I thought was a *likely* answer.  I still maintain it is a poor riddle if there is no clear answer, and you're just choosing one among many.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham Oof, that was a little... assertive. Nice answer though! :P